# Find the good substring of length K such that it has the least importance

Tags: algorithm

> Define a good substring as a substring which begins with 'x', ends with 'z' and has a length divisible by 3. Define the importance of a string as the number of good substrings it intersects with (excluding itself, if it is itself good). Consider a string of length N (1≤N≤10^5) which is composed of x,y,z. Given an integer K(1≤K≤10^5), find the good substring that has the minimum importance and is of length K. You need to print the minimum importance.

I have an idea to solve this but I can't really code it up. Firstly it has to be done in linear/linearithmic time.

What I thought is, store at beg[i] the number of good substrings that originate from i. This can be done if we use a counter from the right end and add according to the modulo 3 position of 'z' towards the right. If i%3==j, then beg[i]=number of 'z' in position j+2 mod 3 to the right of i. Similarly we can create end[i] to get the number of good substrings that end at i. If i position contains a 'y' or if it does not form a good substring we will write beg[i] or end[i] equal to 0.

Now for the next part (finding the intersections), I'm not sure of how to yield a linear/linearithmic solution. 
For a particular interval [arr[i],arr[i+K-1]], the number of intersections will be

= num of substrings which begin before a[i] - num of subs which end before a[i] + number of subs which begins after a[i] and ends before, at, after a[i+K-1].

This is the idea. I'm sure that there's some way to do pre-computations and maybe modify the above equation I wrote so as to yield the answer.

Comment: @juvian updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that accumulated[i] = how many good strings start on index i or greater. There might be a mistake in the answer formula but the idea should be correct.

```
for i = 0 to N
    beg[i] = end[i] = 0

for i = 0 to 3
    z[i] = 0
    x[i] = 0

for i = 0 to N
    if str[i] == 'z'
        z[i % 3]++

for i = 0 to N
   if str[i] == 'z'
       z[i % 3]--
       end[i] = x[i % 3]
   if str[i] == 'x'
       beg[i] = z[i % 3]
       x[i % 3]++
       total += beg[i]

for i = 0 to N
    accumulated[i] = total
    total -= beg[i]

answer = N + 1

beforeStart = beforeEnd = 0
for i = 0 to N - k
    if str[i] == 'x' and str[i + k] == 'z'
        answer = min(answer, beforeStart - beforeEnd + (accumulated[i + k] - accumulated[i]) + beg[i] - 1)

    beforeStart += beg[i]
    beforeEnd += end[i]

print(answer)
```